# Update AppStore connect build version

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Our app was uploaded to our AppStore connect account with incorrect version. Supposedly the app should have a version 1001.200211, but we incorrectly entered 1010.200211 which is too large.

The first number in our version 1001 indicates the iteration number the release happen, the expected next version would be 1002 or 1003 but since we already entered 1010.200211 the next release versions no longer valid and will not be accepted!

Is there a way to update the build version after it has been uploaded in our AppStore connect account?

Comment: No you can't because There is no way to delete a build from the Appstore. So, Appstore will only accept build having higher version.

Comment: Have you submitted version 1010 for review? If not then just upload the right version number And make sure you change the version in the app details in AppStore connect. If you have then you have to release 1011 next.

Comment: @Paulw11 not yet, but the problem is the right 1001.###### which is lower than 1010.######. Apple doesn't allowed it.

Comment: If the problem is in the build field then yes, there is nothing you can do.  Build numbers must always go up

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to change the build version of an app. You may be able to contact Apple Support to help you with this by deleting that binary but there's no way to do this yourself.

Comment: I contacted the Apple support but they say it can't be deleted. I guess we have to reconstruct our version number from this mistake.